# ¿Como hallar la diferencia de tiempo entre 2 TimeSelector?

Tags: asp.net

lo que busco es que al momento de seleccionar una hora especifica en cada TimeSelector me muestre en un textBox el tiempo de diferencia entre el timeSelector1 y el timeSelector2 .
Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
  Dim h1, m1, h2, m2, totalm, totalh As Int16
    h1 = Convert.ToInt16(TimeSelector1.Hour)
    h2 = Convert.ToInt16(TimeSelector2.Hour)
    m1 = Convert.ToInt16(TimeSelector1.Minute)
    m2 = Convert.ToInt16(TimeSelector2.Minute)
    totalh = h2 - h1
    totalm = m2 - m1
    TextBox3.Text = totalh.ToString() + " : " + totalm.ToString()
```

De esta manera resto la hora final con la hora inicial y el resultado es:

9:15-10:20 = 1:5 
ahí no hay problema

Ahora si los valores son:

9:20-9:15 = 1:-5 
El resultado es 1 hora y 5 minutos.

Lo que realmente deberia calcular es que son 55 minutos de diferencia.

Comment: Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender tu problema.

Comment: Lo logre hacer de la siguiente manera:                                                                                                            Dim horaInicio As DateTime = TimeSelector1.Date
        Dim horaFinal As DateTime = TimeSelector2.Date
        Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFinal.Subtract(horaInicio)
        TextBox3.Text = diferencia.ToString()

Comment: Hola Yulfredy, ¿podrías publicar tu solución como respuesta? La idea es que tal vez alguien con el mismo problema encuentre útil la forma en que lo resolviste. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera se puede obtener la diferencia de tiempo transcurrido entre los dos TimeSelector:

```
Dim horaInicio As DateTime = TimeSelector1.Date 
Dim horaFinal As DateTime = TimeSelector2.Date 
Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = horaFinal.Subtract(horaInicio)
TextBox3.Text = diferencia.ToString()
```

Comment: Gracias por colocar tu respuesta, Yulfredy. Aquí puedes aprender [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español.